# click event does not work on the text which is created by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code that you see under the text, there is a `<div>` and in it I wrote "Hello World" . I coded based on jQuery that when I click `<div>` that class name is `test` it creates a new `<div class="test">..` .

The problem is that when I click on the new element which is generated with class name `test` with text "Book", it does not create new element, where as if I click on "Hello World", it generates new element again.

If anyone helps me to solve this problem, I will be thankful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".test").click(function(){
            $(this).after('<div class="test">Book</div>');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test">
        Hello World
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".test").click(function(){
    $(this).after('<div class="test">Book</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="test">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: The newly created element `Book` has no event attached to it. Your script to bind click event on `.test` elements only work once when document is ready. In order to solve this problem, try binding the event after the element is created.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `click()` only works for elements that already existed when the page loaded. Try the following using `on()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.test', function () {
     $(this).after('<div class="test">Book</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
<div class="test">
    Hello World
</div>
```

The `on` event attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements wherever the elements are on the body.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegates for handling the events fired by elements that are created at runtime see the following code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").delegate(".test", "click", function(){
            $(this).after('<div class="test">Book</div>');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    

<div class="test">
Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is only bound to elements that are already present. In order for it to work on new elements, you need to unbind the event handler on all elements and re-bind it again, or add the event binding to the new element. The second option is shown below.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var clickHandler = function(){
            var newElem = $('<div class="test">Book</div>');
            newElem.on("click", clickHandler);
            newElem.insertAfter(this);
        };
        $(".test").on("click", clickHandler);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    

<div class="test">
Hello World
</div>
```